# Differential Form Over $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential

I was checking problems on differential forms and I found the following one.

Consider the sphere $S^2 \subseteq R^3$ and the map $\omega_p : T_pS^2 \times T_pS^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\omega_p(X_p,Y_p) = (X_p \times Y_p) \cdot p$.

Globally, $\omega$ defines a differential $2$-form over $S^2$. And what about if I want to compute $\int_{S^2} w$.

I think that $X_p \times Y_p = \pm p$, so $\omega_p$ would have a simpliest form. Is that true?

How can I write $\omega = f d\theta \wedge d\phi$ in order to compute the integral?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write down the parametric form:
$$
p=(x,y,z)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)
$$
Now the two derivations (tangent vectors) can be computed by:
$$
\begin{split}
\partial/\partial\theta&=(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,-\sin\theta)\\
\partial/\partial\phi&=(-\sin\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,0)
\end{split}
$$
The only thing left is to compute $f$ in $\omega=fd\theta\wedge d\phi=f(d\theta\otimes d\phi-d\phi\otimes d\theta)$. For this, we plug in $\partial/\partial\theta,\partial/\partial\phi$ to get:
$$
\begin{split}
f&=(\partial/\partial\theta\times\partial/\partial\phi)\cdot p\\
 &=\sin\theta
\end{split}
$$
And therefore:
$$
\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta=4\pi
$$

Comment: Thank you! What illustrative response.